# Page Loading Speed - Product Catalog

Tags: performance, magento, load

I have come accross this website. http://en.colette.fr/women/just-in.html

If you notice, the products are loaded with lightning speed. I understand they are using Magento. However, its still not clear how the products are loaded so fast. Can you guys give an idea what's hapening there. Is it the server or a plugin that caches the products with some super technique.

I really appreciate your time and favorable comments.

Regards,

Faisal

Comment: You should ask this question on http://magento.stackexchange.com. Stackoverflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are few step for speed up catalog page:

```
Enable the Flat Catalog module for products and categories in the Magento Admin Panel. We have seen quite significant improvements by turning on this feature, especially on large catalogs.
Where: System -> Configuration -> Catalog
Enable caching to reduce the number of database operations required for each page request.
Where: System -> Cache Management
```

More details on https://web.archive.org/web/20140327173649/http://www.gxjansen.com/101-ways-to-speed-up-your-magento-e-commerce-website/

Answer (score 0):

It seems they are using [Lesti Full Page Cache module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/lesti-fpc.html) and Varnish.
I noticed the Age header in the response headers:

[image]

The Age is usually sent by Lesti::FPC